# What is the use of Eureka Server in Microservices architecture

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using "Spring Cloud Gateway" in my microservices application
Ex:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=mydemoservice
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://localhost:8100/
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/mydemoservice/**
```

In this case if the request is coming from client like : http://localhost:8100/mydemoservice/api/getdetails
in this case "Spring Cloud Gateway" will route the request to respective service.
But why is **Eureka Server** required here ? I am not really understanding Eureka Server use here can some please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Best I could find is this medium article which depicts the problems and solutions Eureka provides.

https://medium.com/javarevisited/how-to-use-spring-cloud-gateway-to-dynamically-discover-microservices-194c0c3869c6

This comes to shine when you deploy services with horizontal auto scalability (such as kubernetes). At certain moments, based on the equation you configure (recourse usage, client connections, etc.) the orchestration can and will scale your services (e.g. mydemoservice). It can scale your service instance up to:

- the configured max number of instances
- until the service usage limit is reached

either way, all of them will have different IP addresses.

Eureka is a discovery/registry service which provides to your gateway information of which cluster/load balancer (IP address) will it pass the request based on Round Robins and such algorithms. The gateway needs to configure all of the services but it will use aliases provided by the Eureka server depicted as such:
https://github.com/rubykv/code-examples/blob/master/gateway/src/main/resources/application.yml
In this example, we see the gateways are configured for services: subject, student, and eureka.

Eureka has a dashboard:
https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*KgT1_hnuXvX6xldyiJJuaQ.png

and will display all eureka clients. To display a service as a eureka client one must implement:

- https://github.com/rubykv/code-examples/blob/master/student/pom.xml (netflix eureka and open feign)
- annotate application with @EnableFeignClients https://github.com/rubykv/code-examples/blob/master/student/src/main/java/com/example/demo/StudentApplication.java

There are lots of tutorials and articles on medium, I hope this helps for your further investigation.

Comment: In addition, eureka server is required or not should be based only on your requirements. If it is only one instance of the microservice, then there is no need for eureka since there will never be more of such microservice at no point in time.